# Find and show duplicates then also show 2 other columns - simple syntax issue or create view or?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, sanitize

I'm checking databases to identify duplicate entries, and while I can do that, I also need to have some other columns (like active, user id) show up in the results so I can then sanitize the database.  It seems simple, but I can't get my attempts to work.
Using MSSQL, need the general approach as much as anything.
So, to recap, almost complicated query to identify duplicates is working, but I can't yet make the results also simply show things like "user is active" or "user is #4367" in my final output.
Thanks in advance.  I thought CREATE VIEW might be an answer, but no luck yet.  JOIN seems too complicated and operative, WHERE chokes (bad syntax?)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  You want to check the duplicates inside databases? Or in a table? Please show us the DDL and your attempt script so others can help.

Comment: I get my duplicates to show with SELECT fullname FROM users GROUP by fullname HAVING ( COUNT(fullname) > 1 )        But when I try to add "okay, now also please show other columns, for the user id, or if they're still active in the database or not, it chokes.  Deal with databases of 10's to 100's of people who change and sometimes recur

Comment: Kevin, If you edit your question in response to comments, it will be more readable than adding your own comment that contains the requested information.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Group By`, and add extra columns, you're also grouping by the additional columns.

You need a subquery and an ungrouped main query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE fullname IN (SELECT fullname 
                   FROM users 
                   GROUP by fullname 
                   HAVING ( COUNT(fullname) > 1 ))
```

You may also want to change the `SELECT *` to `SELECT DISTINCT *` above.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use self join.  Something like this (where Value is what you are checking for duplicate on ID is the unique rowID and UserID is another value to report on):

```
 SELECT a.Value, a.ID, a.UserID
   FROM MyTable a
   JOIN MyTable b
     ON (a.Value = b.Value and a.ID <> b.ID)
  ORDER BY a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version (hopefully you are), it is easy to use COUNT() OVER for this:

```
SELECT
  YourGroupByColumn,
  SomeOtherColumn1,
  SomeOtherColumn2
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY YourGroupByColumn)
    FROM
      dbo.YourTable
  ) AS s
WHERE
  cnt > 1
;
```

Using COUNT() OVER allows you to get aggregated data (counts) alongside detail data. In order to filter on the aggregated results obtained in this way, you need to use the result set with the counts as a derived table and reference the counts column in the outer query's WHERE clause, which is what the above query does.